# Positive semidefiniteness of a RKHS

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, positive-semidefinite, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I do not get the derivation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space) which states that a RHKS is PSD. Specifically, I can see that if the kernel is PSD, then $\langle K_x, K_y \rangle$ must be PSD since $K(x, y)$ is PSD.

I do not, however, get the final step of the derivation on wikipedia:

$$
\sum_{i,j =1}^n c_i c_j K(x_i, x_j)=
\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \left\langle K_{x_i} , \sum_{j=1}^n c_j K_{x_j} \right\rangle_{H} = 
 \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n c_i K_{x_i} , \sum_{j=1}^n c_j K_{x_j} \right\rangle_{H} =
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^nc_iK_{x_i}\right\|_H^2 \ge  0
$$

How does the $j$ index completely disappear and turn into the norm only over the $i$ index? I feel like I am missing something simple here...

Comment: $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$?

Comment: @angryavian, I see that this is true for the coefficients, but  $K_{x_i}$ and $K_{x_j}$ are different, so I do not see how $K_{x_j}$ can suddenly be replaced by $K_{x_i}$

Comment: Both terms in the last inner product are $c_1 K_{x_1} + c_2 K_{x_2} + \cdots + c_n K_{x_n}$. Whether you index by $i$ or $j$ does not matter.

Comment: Oh right yeah that should have been obvious, the notation earlier in the section threw me off for some reason where it mentioned some $K_x$ as being anchored to a particular $x$